# Carousel Images and content are not displaying

Tags: carousel, bootstrap-5

I have replicate this code to get 2 column structure in which left side is image carousel and right side is some text, I got the text right but the carousel is not displaying, I am using bootstrap-5 and have linked correct bootstrap css and js, that's verified:

Here is my code:

```html
<section class="tech-area analytics-area" id="analytics-section">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <!-- carousel goes here -->
                    <div id="feature-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                        <div class="carousel-indicators">
                            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#feature-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#feature-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#feature-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
                            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#feature-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="3" aria-label="Slide 4"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-inner active">
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <!-- first image -->
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/images/FiMobile-1-300x400.png" alt="slider-img1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <!-- second image -->
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/images/FiMobile-1-300x400.png" alt="slider-img2">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <!-- third image -->
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/images/FiMobile-1-300x400.png" alt="slider-img3">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <!-- fourth image -->
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/images/FiMobile-1-300x400.png" alt="slider-img4">
                            </div>
                        </div>



                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <!-- Right side text goes here -->
                    <h1>Best UI UX design with analytical dashboard and more…</h1>
                    <p>Template provide best designed and user experienced home page and analytical dashboard. Gives
                        rich feeling and easy use elements action available with different interface design.</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Menu push content and overlay menu also full screen menu provided.</li>
                        <li>Sticky Footer iconic footer menu and informative footer for inner page</li>
                        <li>Dark mode with Different color selection to match your brand and stay with trend.</li>
                        <li>Customer will get Framework choice with same design to build app.</li>
                        <li>We have built template with responsive layout grid , It gives small to large phone devices
                            and UI support back to tablet devices also.</li>
                        <li>Standard grid systems are easy to customize as per need which adds flexibility components
                            designs.</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Try this - https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel

Comment: Got the issue. The "active" class is placed at wrong div.

Comment: carousel working perfectly in `https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel`. `active` class should be placed with `carousel-item` class, not with `carousel-inner`.

Answer (score 0):

You added the `active` class in the wrong element. Instead of the `carousel-inside` element, the `active` class must be used to mark one of the `carousel-item` elements as the initial active one:

```html
<section class="tech-area analytics-area" id="analytics-section">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <!-- carousel goes here -->
                    <div id="feature-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                        <div class="carousel-indicators">
                            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#feature-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#feature-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#feature-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
                            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#feature-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="3" aria-label="Slide 4"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <!-- first image -->
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/images/FiMobile-1-300x400.png" alt="slider-img1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <!-- second image -->
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/images/FiMobile-1-300x400.png" alt="slider-img2">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <!-- third image -->
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/images/FiMobile-1-300x400.png" alt="slider-img3">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <!-- fourth image -->
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/images/FiMobile-1-300x400.png" alt="slider-img4">
                            </div>
                        </div>



                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <!-- Right side text goes here -->
                    <h1>Best UI UX design with analytical dashboard and more…</h1>
                    <p>Template provide best designed and user experienced home page and analytical dashboard. Gives
                        rich feeling and easy use elements action available with different interface design.</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Menu push content and overlay menu also full screen menu provided.</li>
                        <li>Sticky Footer iconic footer menu and informative footer for inner page</li>
                        <li>Dark mode with Different color selection to match your brand and stay with trend.</li>
                        <li>Customer will get Framework choice with same design to build app.</li>
                        <li>We have built template with responsive layout grid , It gives small to large phone devices
                            and UI support back to tablet devices also.</li>
                        <li>Standard grid systems are easy to customize as per need which adds flexibility components
                            designs.</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```